# Where to store CMS images with Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a cms system. This will be going to production so i want to get it right in the first time. The cms is similar to a blog articles, I was wondering how to handle images with Node JS, More specifically whether these images be stored in the Database using gridfs or on some cloud service like cloudinary. Some advice on this matter would be much appreciated. If some one could enlighten me on good node js cms practicies, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cloud service like Cloudinary will be best. There are NPM packages that can help you do that easily with NodeJS. I usually push all the images to Cloudinary with the packages. It returns a publicly accessible link for the image. I store that on the db.

These are the packages I use: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use amazon s3 bucket or you can save it in public folder of your project.
you can do it using Node multer for saving images in you project folder. below is link.
```

npm Multer Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer